# Sencha Touch large html rendering is slow

Tags: javascript, performance, optimization, sencha-touch

we build a Sencha Touch application, which allows to search and display html documents. Nothing special, simple html document which user can scroll up and down.

Some of the documents are pretty big ~ 5mb of pure html. These documents slow down the application, sometimes it even crashes.

Do you have any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

5mb-size HTML file is very large, even for laptop browser. If you run it on mobile devices browsers than there's a very high probability that they will be crashed. (Nearly 100% for BlackBerry browsers.)

It's highly recommended that you should keep the size of each HTML file not exceed several hundred KBs (let's say 500KB). Then in each of your HTML files, provide "Read more" button for the users to navigate to the next chapter of your HTML content.

Please keep in mind that, the more complex the DOM is, the slower your Sencha Touch application will become, as it always has to completely manage your DOM structure.